# How do I validate User role on Laravel 5.8s Built in Authentication?

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.8, laravel-authentication

I've a User Role column on my User's table.

- stands for Super Admin,
- stands for other users

I've checked a lot of Laravel Tutorials and none of them has helped me about solving this issue.

I've found ways like replacing the whole Laravel's `Login Controller` and replacing Authenticate Users trait with ours own. I want to solve my problem with minimal code change. Is it possible?

How do I implement it with minimal code changes in this Trait method?

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);


    if (method_exists($this, 'hasTooManyLoginAttempts') &&
        $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
    }


    $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
```

Comment: What you want to validate? That the role field is required?

Comment: I want to check if the User has give role of 1. I found the solution :D

Comment: But how can I change  "These credentials do not match our records." and instead show "Only Super Admins are allowed"?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44881034/laravel-5-4-show-error-message-auth-login-when-user-is-not-active) or [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-auth-with-custom-error-messages)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something as supersimple as adding a isSuperAdmin function to the User model. After logging in you just call this function on the user whenever you need to check.

**In model User.php**

```
  public function isSuperAdmin()
  {
      return $this->user_role == 1;
  }
```

---

Then you could also make a middleware that's using this function.

```
php artisan make:middleware SuperAdmin
```

In the handle function of this middleware (*app/http/middleware/SuperAdmin.php*):

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isSuperAdmin()) {
        return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect('some-route-for-unauthorized-users');

}
```

Then in your routes (probably web.php), you can use this middleware to protect routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'superadmin']], function () {
    ... put protected routes here ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
        /**
         * Create a new controller instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct() {
            $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        }

        protected function credentials(Request $request)
        {
            $credentials = $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
            $credentials['role'] = '1';
            return $credentials;
        }
```